# Error conecting a ruby script to a Mysql database running on Ec2

Tags: mysql, ruby, linux, amazon-ec2, mysql2

I created a small script in Ruby to see if I could manipulate data on a mysql database on an Amazon Ec2 AMI (Ubuntu 64b). I added SSH and MYSQL to the permissions under the instance's security group. I was able to connect the script to the database (using the mysql2 gem) but it no longer works and I don't understand why I keep having the error:

> mysql2/client.rb:58:in `connect': Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'XX.XXX.XX.XXX (60) (Mysql2::Error)

This is the script i'm using

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'
require 'net/ssh/gateway'


gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
           'ec2-user',
           :keys => ['/XXXX/XXXXX.pem'])
port = gateway.open("XX.XXX.XX.XXX",3306,3307)

baseDeDatos= Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "XX.XXX.XX.XXX", :database=> "x" ,:username => "x", :password => "x")

puts "I made it!"

baseDeDatos.close

gateway.close(port)
gateway.shutdown!'
```

Is there someone who can shed a light on my problem? I'm confused as it worked some days ago and no it doesn't (I haven't changed any permissions or anything). Of course I checked that the MYSQL database is working properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you did not grant remote permissions on the mysql db side? By default those permissions are not available.

Edit:
 If the connection is made from within the ec2 instance but not outside it, then you definitely have not done a grant permissions on the user.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I added permissions for my remote ip but unfortunately it is still displaying the same error.